# draw object/image on canvas

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

Is there another way to draw an object on a canvas in android?

This code inside draw() doesn't work:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);

         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);
```

Well actually, it's working on my 1st code but when I've transfered this to another class called MarkOverlay, it's not working anymore.

```
  markerOverlay = new MarkerOverlay(getApplicationContext(), p);
                      listOfOverlays.add(markerOverlay);
```

What parameter should I pass to MarkerOverlay to make this code work? The error is somewhere in getResources().

FYI, canvas.drawOval is perfectly working but I really want to draw an Image not an Oval. :)

Answer (score 41):

I prefer to do this as it only generates the image once:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Drawable mCustomImage;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mCustomImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
    }

    ...

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect imageBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();  // Adjust this for where you want it

        mCustomImage.setBounds(imageBounds);
        mCustomImage.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for not making allocations or unpacking an image in onDraw

Comment: gives me this eclipse warning: Avoid object allocations during draw operations: Use Canvas.getClipBounds(Rect) instead of Canvas.getClipBounds() which allocates a temporary Rect

Comment: This can be made even better if you follow the simple optimizer hits given by Eclipse. Ie. 

  canvas.getClipBounds(imageBounds); 
  mCustomImage.setBounds(imageBounds);

Having a super fast onDraw is very important.

Comment: `getResources().getDrawable()` is deprecated as of API 22. Use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);` instead.

Answer (score 26):

```
package com.canvas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Keypaint extends View {
    Paint p;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        p=new Paint();
        Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
    }

    public Keypaint(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to free up Bitmap data with Bitmap.recycle() or else you get a nasty memory leak: creating a new bitmap in every drawing cycle.

Comment: Dont decode image in onDraw - do as much of the heavy lifting outside the render loop.

Comment: is it possible to set video view on canvas?