# Adding text on top of an image using a Canvas - Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

I want to add some text on top of an image.
I read the image from the sd card and set it to a Bitmap variable.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then I added it to a canvas. The code I used is given below,

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(myBitmap);
```

But when I added this line, the app crashed at that point. Why is it and how can i solve this ??

Note : Above mention code lines are inside `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172523/draw-object-image-on-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app crash because your

> BitmapFactory.decodeFile

return a immutable bitmap and `public Canvas (Bitmap bitmap)` only accept a mutable bitmap.

To solve your problem you must convert your immutable Bitmap into mutable [see here the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu/9194259#9194259)

If you target only >= API 11 , you can use

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```