# Real name of "all frames in one image" images?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I dont know how these kind of "all frames in one image" images are called. Please, can you tell me how these images are called?

I can't find any info

Answer (score 0):

Use a canvas, drawing an image in the onDraw() function, and setting a new image to be drawn in the update function each time.

For a detailed tutorial, look at this:
http://jmsliu.com/2306/android-canvas-example-draw-sprite-sheet-animation-on-canvas.html

EDIT:
Oops, paid tutorial!
Well, try this instead.
For using the canvas to make an animation:
[How to animate a path on canvas - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android)

You don't want to animate a path, but draw images.
Use this answer:
[draw object/image on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172523/draw-object-image-on-canvas)

Now, instead of transformations to the path in onDraw(), just keep drawing the next image in the series.

Comment: this tutorial asks for money!

Answer (score -2):

They're called spritesheets.

I don't have any info on how to animate them on an android platform though.

Comment: this should be a comment since this does not answer the question

Comment: Aha. Thanks, didn't know.